# Why Could is used in both past and the future tense

Tags: word-usage, past-tense, could-modal, future-constructions

Why Could is used in both past and the future tense?
Example:

> I could run fast when I was younger.
> Extreme rain could cause the river to flood the city.

Can 'Could' be considered as a homonym.
Same question applies to 'Would' also.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Homonym - 1. One of two or more words that have the same sound and often the same spelling but differ in meaning, such as bank (embankment) and bank (place where money is kept).

Comment: The first "could" has the same meaning as "used to be able to". The second "could" means future possibility. They can only be told apart from the context

Answer (score 0):

The Old English "cunnan" had an past subjunctive "cuþe" which was the same as past indicative. When the English verbs simplified, the past subjunctive became "could" and was used for a variety of contexts in which a subjunctive form of "can" is needed (whether in the past, present or future)

So "I could play tennis tomorrow" = "I might be able (subjunctive) to play tennis tomorrow if..."  is a context in which Old English would use a subjunctive. The present subjunctive (cunne) has been lost and replaced by the past subjunctive, and then as other subjunctive forms have been lost, the use of "could" has remained as a fossil.

...

The practical answer for modern English is probably "Because that's how English is".

Comment: That is a fascinating historical analysis.  (Seriously, not joking.)  The practical answer for modern English is probably "Because that's how English is", though.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Because it doesn't always have a tense.  It often expresses something else by its so-called past-tense form.

English has a small group of verbs that are typically called *modal auxiliaries*.  The list includes *can/could, will/would, shall/should, may/might, and [mote]*/must.*

These modal auxiliaries are all *defective* verbs, and they're all defective in the same way.  They don't have the usual non-finite forms.  They also lack a distinct third-person singular form.

You could consider the past-tense forms and the subjunctive-mode forms to be similar to homonyms.  You could even go a step further by considering them *syncretic forms* -- forms that are likely related to historically distinct forms in the evolution of the language.

They aren't quite homonyms because they aren't quite different words, not in the sense that usually matters.  They aren't separate lexemes.  An example of separate lexemes that deserve to be called homonyms is *can* and *can*, where one is the modal auxiliary related to *being able to* and the other is the transitive verb related to *an object's placement in a canister*.**

Regardless of label, it is still the right idea.

We can apply that idea to weak and strong regular verbs, as well.  The strong regular verbs have distinct forms for the past tense and the so-called past participle -- a *vowel shift / -en* distinction, as in *give(s)/gave/given*.  The more common weak regular verbs have syncretic forms -- *-ed* for both, as in *work(s)/worked/worked*.

_______________

* The form "mote" is obsolete.  I've only encountered it in the Wiccan phrasing "so mote it be", as a parallel to the Abrahamic "amen".  We might want to regard *must* as a slightly more defective verb, lacking its present and indicative forms as well as its non-finite forms.

** The transitive verb is not defective.  Phrases like "canned peaches", "canning peaches" and "to can peaches" are all available and sensible.  Additionally, "he *cans* peaches" is distinct from "they *can* peaches".